# JSONObject.write(<a writer>) vs. aWriter.write(jSONObj.toString())

Tags: java, writer, json

It seems like there're 2 ways to write the content of a JSON object to a writer. I can either do

```
myWriter.write(myJSONObj.toString());
```

Or

```
myJSONObj.write(myWriter);
```

Is there any reason why anyone would choose one way over the other?

Comment: Which library do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java):

```
public String toString() {
    try {
        return this.toString(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String toString(int indentFactor) throws JSONException {
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    synchronized (w.getBuffer()) {
        return this.write(w, indentFactor, 0).toString();
    }
}

public Writer write(Writer writer) throws JSONException {
    return this.write(writer, 0, 0);
}
```

so basically, the first approach:

```
myWriter.write(myJSONObj.toString());
```

1. Creates a `StringWriter`.
2. Passes the writer to `write(Writer writer, int indentFactor, int indent)`.
3. The JSON content get written to the writer.
4. The content of the writer is converted via `StringWriter#toString()`.
5. The final string get written to `myWriter`.

The second approach:

```
myJSONObj.write(myWriter);
```

1. Passes the writer to `write(Writer writer, int indentFactor, int indent)`.
2. The JSON content get written to the writer.

Comment: So for the second approach, other than saving me some StringWriter creation, it doesn't do much else...